# "Capture" command seems to ignore iter(#) option of -xtlogit- using Stata

Tags: stata

I am running a .do-file which includes many models estimated by `xtlogit`. Even if a model does not converge I would like to document this in the log. As the .do-file takes some hours to run, I normally go away and do something else. Unfortunately, the non-convergence of a model stops the whole .do-file. 
Therefore, I used `capture noisily {}` in order to run the whole .do-file. However, this seems to ignore the maximum number of iterations I have specified in each `xtlogit` command separately depending on the number of variables and the assumed complexity of the model.

I already found a workaround by using `set maxiter` globally before running the models. But this does not allow for a finer specification of iterations per model (unless I use it **a lot**).

I could not find any reports about this behaviour of `capture`. Maybe, there is a better approach to this than my workaround with `set maxiter`?

Here is an example code which reproduces the error manually by imposing too few iterations:

```
webuse union, clear
capture noisily {
xtlogit union age grade i.not_smsa south##c.year, fe iter(2)
xtlogit union age grade i.not_smsa south##c.year, iter(3) pa
xtlogit union age grade i.not_smsa south##c.year, fe iter(2)
}
```

The .do-file stops after the second model with an error message "convergence not achieved"
`r(430);` and does not proceed with the third model as I would suspect because of `capture`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with [this code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpkx3so_071113_1.do2sqjhfk3q4/). iter() works fine here.

Comment: I will try to make some reproducible code relying on example datasets.

Comment: My previous link is broken. Sorry about that. [This one](https://github.com/refp16/stackexchange/blob/master/so_071113_1.do) works.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer: I have added an example. Maybe you can now also reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are applying `capture` at the wrong level. You want to `capture` any error in `xtlogit` rather than of the whole do-file.

In addition, check out the `nostop` option of `do`.

Comment: I have added an example. Maybe you can now also reproduce the error?

Comment: Same comment. It's not a block you want to `capture`, but each individual command.

Comment: That is a pity. I have thought that there might be a less tedious way than to write a `capture` command for each `xtlogit` model.

Comment: Why the fuss? Use a loop, or use any decent text editor to replace `xtlogit` with `capture xtlogit` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This works and respects your individual `iter`s:

```
webuse union, clear
capture noisily xtlogit union age grade i.not_smsa south##c.year, pa iter(3)
xtlogit union age grade i.not_smsa south##c.year, fe iter(2)
xtlogit union age grade i.not_smsa south##c.year, fe iter(3)
```

Notice there is a difference in the behavior of `xtlogit` depending on whether
you use the `fe` or `pa` option. Failure to converge with the former *does not*
result in the do-file stopping as it does when there is failure to converge
with the latter. That is why I only put `capture noisily` in the first line.

Maybe a more experienced user can 
comment on this. If not, you can contact Stata-tech support.

Bottom line, as @NickCox already mentioned, you can avoid your specific problem
adjusting the location of your `capture`.

Comment: I was also surprised that only the `pa` option stops the .do-file.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out why this happens because I was running into a similar problem where xtlogit seems to disobey the iterate(#) command. The reason is that it is computing two separate models: the comparison model, and the full model. It applies iterate(#) to the full model and not the comparison model. Because the comparison model gets fitted first, you can see the iterations pass beyond iterate(#). Set maxiter solved it for me thanks to your question!